# php function works in localhost but doesn't on the server

Tags: php, localhost

When I try to put my website in production, i get an error, but everything works well in my wamp localhost.

The error =>

- Type: ErrorException
- Code: 8
- Message: Undefined offset: 0
- File: *******/httpdocs/alliance/slimrest/datamanager/dm_utilisateur.php
- Line: 20

Le line 20 is the last of this code portion =>

```
    $user = $o_utilisateur->getUserByLogPass($log, $pass);

    if(isset($user['0'])){
        //GET group BY user
        $tmp = $o_droit->getGroupById($user['0']['TB_groupe_id_groupe']);
        $user['0']['libele'] = $tmp['0']['libele'];
```

I might be the PHP version ?

- Localhost : PHP_VERSION = 5.5.12
- Server : PHP_VERSION = 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4

Comment: Change all occurrences of `$user['0']` to `$user[0]`

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($user); exit;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You checked `isset($user['0'])`, but not `isset($tmp['0'])`. The problem must be with the `$tmp` variable, it has no `0` key.

```
if(isset($user['0']) && isset($tmp['0']))
```

I don't know what `$tmp` is supposed to contain, but for some reason it doesn't contain it on your production server. You need to check whatever code creates the `$tmp` array, perhaps it's a database problem, did you upload the DB to production?

Comment: Thanx, you were right, the problem was that the SQL version of my localhost understood my SQL request ( SELECT * FROM TB_rights ) but the SQL version of the server didn't. I had to change my request to : ( SELECT * FROM `tb_rights` ).